# Is there a way to destructure a property from useSelector

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As the title say, is there a way to destructure a property from useSelector.

```
const { content, loading, loaded } = useSelector(state => ({
  content: state.supply.content,
  loading: state.supply.loading,
  loaded: state.supply.loaded,
}))
```

using this typed hook:

```
import { useSelector as useReduxSelector, shallowEqual, TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux"

export const useSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<AppState> = (selector, equalityFn = shallowEqual) =>
  useReduxSelector(selector, equalityFn)
```

`content` property set to value depending on an action

```
type RequestItems = {
  category: Category;
  items: Array<Item>;
  totalCountFromServer: number;
}

export type RequestItem = {
  item: Item;
}

export type RequestCategories = {
  categories: Array<Category>
}

type RequestContent =
  | RequestItem
  | RequestItems
  | RequestCategories

type State = {
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
  content: RequestContent | undefined
}
```

I want to get something similar to this, but I get type error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')`.

```
 const { items, category, totalCountFromServer, loading, loaded, error } = useSelector(state => ({
    items: (state.supply.content as RequestItems).items,
    category: (state.supply.content as RequestItems).category,
    totalCountFromServer: (state.supply.content as RequestItems).totalCountFromServer,
    loading: state.supply.loading,
    loaded: state.supply.loaded,
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

the destructuring should not be the issue here. It's just that call to `useSelector` is returning undefined so cannot access properties from that result.

It's like if you were doing `useSelector(...).items`. If you know it can be undefined you would want to access it conditionally like `useSelector(...)?.items`.

If you know it can be undefined and want to do something similar with destructuring you can fall back to an empty object like `const {items} = useSelector(...)||{}`.

Or possibly the error is on the next lines at

```
   items: (state.supply.content as RequestItems).items,
```

Then here you can just access conditionally `?.items`